# Org Mode: Org-Meta-Newline removes excess newlines

Tags: org-mode

When running emacs as `emacs -nw -q` and opening an org-file, insertion of headings goes as follows (`X` represents the cursor):

```
* Heading 1
* Heading 2


X
```

When running `org-meta-return` here, the next headline is inserted at line 3:

```
* Heading 1
* Heading 2
* X
```

As you can see, the whitespace was removed.

Is there a variable I can customize to make it such that running `org-meta-return` results in:

```
* Heading 1
* Heading 2


* X
```

I looked through `customize-group org` and was not able to find a variable that would control this.

Comment: A small workaround I found was to modify `org.el`'s definition of `org-insert-heading` and change the following expression: `(org-N-empty-lines-before-current (if blank? 1 0))` to `(org-N-empty-lines-before-current 3)`, but I would like to know if there are better ways of doing this (creating a variable or something along those lines).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with current Org mode ( 9.3.7). I checked the history and there is one likely bug fix that went in during 9.1.14 and before 9.2 was released. Check your Org version (`M-x org-version RET`) and see if it's  9.1.14 or earlier. If so, I would advise you to upgrade.

Comment: I see that too (version 9.3.7). You may have to change `org-N-empty-lines-before-current` or maybe ask the Org developers for help.

Comment: Also check `org-blank-before-new-entry`. The `auto` values seemed to be playing tricks on me, but setting both `heading` and `plain-list-item` to `t` makes them more predictable (and I like the more relaxed spacing).