# How to prevent org-meta-return from eating my excess newlines?

Tags: org-mode

Pressing `M-RET` in this position:

```
** medium-term
*** clean up our open PRs CARET_HERE


** tags
```

edits to

```
** medium-term
*** clean up our open prs
*** CARET_HERE

** tags
```

This has removed my newlines between the two second-level headers, which I do not want.

I am on org version 9.5.

Related:

- [Org Mode: Org-Meta-Newline removes excess newlines](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59358/org-mode-org-meta-newline-removes-excess-newlines)
- https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/4918

Comment: What two first-level headers? I can only see second- and third-level headers here. When I press `M-RET` at the end of the original third-level header, I get another third-level header inserted where you show it, but the empty lines between that point and the `tags` header does not change. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: @NickD Sorry, I meant second-level headers. Yes, when I use org-insert-heading, it completely erases the excess newlines, no matter how many they are, and keeps a maximum of one empty line between the headers.

Comment: What is the value of `org-insert-heading-hook`?

Comment: @NickD It's `nil`. I use `doom` though, and they might have overridden stuff more deeply than that ... I'll ask them.

Comment: Well, AFAICS there is no place where a newline gets deleted in `org-inserrt-heading`, so this was the only possibility I could see for newlines to be removed. If it's nil, I cannot see any way for that to happen. I would suggest that you learn about [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html) and instrument `org-insert-heading`, then carefully step through it and see where the newlines disappear.